# Where can I see MySQL hostname and port for wp-config.php

Tags: wpdb, wp-config, localhost

Right now in my wp-config.php I have this line:

```
/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost:3306');
```

I see that the default installation of Wordpress configures the file just with the host, not the port. Why is there a port added there and where can I see how it connects to MySQL database?

Is that configuration just applicable when working locally or also in production?

Answer (score 1):

By default, MySQL runs on localhost, which is on the same IP address where the website is hosted. 3306 is the default port for MySQL. Most websites will run with these settings, it depends on your host.

Comment: I just figure it out that although 3306 is the default port, it doesn't need to be specified there. Just the host without the port.

Comment: Indeed, it's not needed since it's the default port. But it doesn't hurt!

Comment: It was giving me some error 2005 Unknown MySQL server host when I placed the port.

Comment: That's interesting!